# Not existing column in "CardinalityEstimate" warning in the execution plan - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, warnings, sql-execution-plan

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and I do merge operation on `AdventureWorks.SalesOrderHeader` table.

When I want to generate an execution plan, I get such a warning:

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o57iR.jpg)

I haven't got column like 'SalesOrderID_OLD' and I don't know where to look for a problem to correct it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please paste your SQL query in your question.

Comment: Warning is related to explicit conversion of data type. It means one of your column data type is not matching with another column data type (And you are trying to compare these two columns).